# Google map lagging after draw poly lines

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I dropped few markers on Google map in my android application and draw poly lines between them. After that Google map is lagging (not scrolling smoothly). I wrote following code to add markers and draw lines.

```
private void dropPointsOnMyRoot() {
    googleMap.clear();

    LatLng l1 = new LatLng(6.932763, 79.843554);
    LatLng l2 = new LatLng(6.933790, 79.850469);
    LatLng l3 = new LatLng(6.911404, 79.848197);
    LatLng l4 = new LatLng(6.894055, 79.853105);
    LatLng l5 = new LatLng(6.712637, 79.904649);
    LatLng l6 = new LatLng(6.584235, 79.959055);
    LatLng l7 = new LatLng(6.433196, 80.000246);
    LatLng l8 = new LatLng(6.277008, 80.043409);
    LatLng l9 = new LatLng(6.235277, 80.054964);

    LatLng[] locations = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9};

    LatLng prevLatLng = null;

    for (LatLng location : locations) {
        addMarker(location);

        if(prevLatLng != null){
            //draw line with current latlong
            String url = makeURL(prevLatLng.latitude, prevLatLng.longitude, location.latitude, location.longitude);

            CallURL callURL = new CallURL(url) {

                @Override
                public void result(String res) {
                    drawPath(res);
                }
            };

            callURL.execute("");

            prevLatLng = location;
        }else{
            prevLatLng = location;
        }
    }

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ambalangoda, 10);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by lag?  Are the map tiles taking longer to load or is the map not scrolling smoothly?  Map tiles loading slowly is most likely due to a slow network connection.  Adding a few markers and polylines should not cause a delay in the map scrolling unless there is a problem in your code that is hogging resources.  Post some code and we can take a look.

Comment: @todd i add some code. can you take a look.